# How to get the URI of a GCP cloud resource?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to get the URI of a compute engine resource? How do you get the URI of any resource in GCP?

Tried to find the URI in the console but could not do so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cloud SDK has the command line option `--uri` which will display the resource URI. This option is not available for all resource types.

For example:

```
gcloud compute instances list --uri
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.